# pass $(this) from iframe element to parent page with onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onclick

I have an iframe that contains

```
<div title="hello" onclick="window.top.iframeclick()"></div>
```

on the parent page, is jquery:

```
 function iframeclick() {
                title = $(this).attr('title');
                alert(title);}
```

the alert is executing, however, it is not updating the variable `title` that is set in the parent page.

Could someone help and explain why it might not reset the `title` variable when I click the iframe's `<div>`, but instead it uses a different element as $(this)?

**Q: how do I pass $(this) from the iframe's div to to be used in a function set in the parent page?**

Comment: Why is there no `var` in your function? You don't need `title` to be a global variable, do you?

Comment: var title is already set as a global variable outside of the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a variable scope problem, check if the title variable is available in the iframeclick function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set `title` to the title from the parent document or the title on the div?

If on the div, the best way IMO would be to pass the value in the function call:

```
<div title="hello" onclick="window.top.iframeclick('hello')"></div>

function iframeclick(myTitle) {
                title = myTitle;
                alert(title);}
```